# TextField returning null

Tags: javafx

Every time I type some text in the `textField` and click the button, to trigger the save () method the text field returns null. What could be causing this?

```
@FXM
private TextField nome = new TextField();

public void save() {
    Model model = new Model();
    model.setNome(nome.getText());
    model.setStatus(status.getSelectedToggle().isSelected());
}


public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    ModelController modelController = new ModelController();
    btnSalvar.setOnAction(event -> modelController.save());
    border.setCenter(modelController.onScreen());
}
```

Comment: Returns `null`? How do you even check this. Furthermore did you initialize `nome` from the fxml or is this simply a field that is initialized to prevent a NPE when accessing it. This way you fix the NPE, but you won't have a field that contains a `TextField` displayed in the scene. Also what kind of annotation is `@FXM`? I'd expect `@FXML`...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this line:

```
@FXM
private TextField nome = new TextField();
```

When you do that you are replacing the reference to the object displayed on screen, to a new one you created. If you want to reference an object created through FXML simply use:

```
@FXML
private TextField nome;
```

the TextField in the FXML file should have an fx:id matching the name of your variable:

```
<TextField fx:id="nome" />
```